# XQuery [modify()]: ")" was expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to replace a XML Node attribute in MS-SQL 2017 and get a error stating 
XQuery [modify()]: ")" was expected. Tried googling it but was not able to figure out any solution.

Below is my xml specs

```
<Identifier xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping">
      <Id idScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/identifier">123456</Id>
</Identifier>
```

I am trying to change the attribute of Id to point it to some other url\namespace

```
Declare @xmlBody xml
SET @xmlBody = N'<Identifier xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping">
      <Id idScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/identifier">123456</Id>
</Identifier>'


SET @xmlBody.modify('declare namespace fpml = "http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping"; 
             replace value of (/fpml/Id@idScheme) with "http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/cftc/issuer-identifier"');


SELECT @xmlBody
```

I am getting a error message as XQuery [modify()]: ")" was expected.

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: You are missing a closing quotation mark on your first `SET @xmlBody`

Comment: `(/fpml:Identifier/fpml:Id/@idScheme)[1]` is the node you're looking for. Alternatively, use `declare default element namespace` so you don't have to stick the `fpml:` everywhere.

Comment: @RyanWilson - That was a typo

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Even that didnt fix  my issue

Comment: `SET @xmlBody.modify('declare default element namespace "http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping"; replace value of (/Identifier/Id/@idScheme)[1] with "http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/cftc/issuer-identifier"');` #worksforme .